# Python script is giving error of attribute while using mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

This is my Python script:

```
import pymongo

from bson.objectid import ObjectId

connection = pymongo.Connection();

db = connection["tutorial"];
employees = db["employees"];

employees.insert({"name": "Lucas Hightower", 'gender':'m', 'phone':'520-555-1212', 'age':8});

cursor = db.employees.find();
for employee in db.employees.find():
    print(employee);

print(employees.find({"name":"Rick Hightower"})[0]);


cursor = employees.find({"age": {"$lt": 35}});
for employee in cursor:
     print("under 35: %s" % employee);


diana = employees.find_one({"_id":ObjectId("4f984cce72320612f8f432bb")});
print("Diana %s" % diana);hon Script:
```

When i am executing the following python i am getting below error:

I am running the script on windows machine

Error: connection = pymongo.Connection();
AttributeError: module 'pymongo' has no attribute 'Connection'

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which version of pymongo you are using. But based on the [latest document](http://api.mongodb.com/python/3.4.0/tutorial.html):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)

db = client["tutorial"]
employees = db["employees"]

employees.insert({"name": "Lucas Hightower", 'gender':'m', 'phone':'520-555-1212', 'age':8})

cursor = employees.find()
for employee in cursor:
    print(employee)
```

Comment: It gives an error of `pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

Comment: It's because you don't run the MongoDB at your localhost.
If you have another Mongodb server, just replace that information.
If you need to run MongoDB at localhost, go to Mongodb's bin folder and run mongod  and remember to create the data folder (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#run-mongodb-community-edition)

Comment: You should check that mongo server is running properly and verify the port number.

Comment: Can you run it now, @AkshayShrivastav?

Comment: Nopes its giving the error still of server socket could not connect to localhost:27017

Comment: Did you try to start MongoDB at your localhost? Follow the link I gave https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#run-mongodb-community-edition